# how to read pdf with google OCR Text in uipath

Tags: uipath

I am new in uipath, I am using **PDF Activity** to read Pdf text with Google OCR, because I want to get pdf text with images in it.

First I have used only Pdf Text,It worked perfectly.
Then I have used Pdf with OCR Then It is showing this Error.

But when I run it It is giving this error:-

```
"Google OCR : Error performing OCR: TessErrorLoadEngine"

Please help me to read the Pdf file.
```

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of this part of your workflow? So we can see the setup

Comment: This is Link through which you can See my workflow..

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLWW8.png

Comment: Have you tried any other engine? UiPath has themselves said you should use the OCR engine from Microsoft for text and Google for numbers.

Comment: Yes I have tried Microsoft OCR engine also but in that case also I was getting this error....

Message: Error performing OCR: MicrosoftErrorCreateEngine

And I have searched out I got to install a new software through this link.
Please tell me is It necessary. I am sharing this link......https://forum.uipath.com/t/ocr-microsoft-ocr-cloud-ocr-abby-ocr-giving-same-error-invalidimageinput/472

Comment: What version of UiPath Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using 2016.2 uipath Version

Comment: Try installing the newest version.

Comment: So what is the reason for this? Is the version that Microsoft OCR activity not working..

Comment: Because of they, in the link you gave, acknowledge that it is a known issue. And they say that as of a certain release the issue should be fixed.

Comment: So, you mean that It is a version problem. right??

Comment: Properly. Just go ahead and try it out

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Nope because I don't have permission to install or update any software.

Answer (score 0):

Use google OCR activity to read image based pdf files. Checkout sample flowchart that I have created for you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ittOc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert PDF containing Images into readable PDF using Online PDF Conversion site and then use the PDF Text activity with new PDF.